# What is the function of Bash "set -e"

Tags: bash

In a bash script what is the use of

```
set -e
```

?

I expect it has something to do with environment variables but I have not come across it before

Comment: What has become of the fine art of reading the fine manual page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quoting from `help set`

> ```
>   -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
> ```

i.e the script or shell would exit as soon as it encounters any command that exited with a non-0(failure) exit code.

Any command that fails would result in the shell exiting immediately.

As an example:

Open up a terminal and type the following:

```
$ set -e
$ grep abcd <<< "abc"
```

As soon you hit enter after `grep` command, the shell exits because `grep` exited with a non-0 status i.e it couldn't find regex `abcd` in text `abc`

Note:  to unset this behavior use `set +e`.

Answer (score 1):

`man bash` says

> Exit  immediately  if a simple command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero
>               status.  The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list
>               immediately  following  a while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement,
>                part of a && or ││ list, or if the command’s return value is being inverted via !.   A
>                         trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits.

It is super convenient way to get "fail-fast" behaviour if you want to avoid testing the return code of every command in a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is no file named **trumpet** in the current directory below  script :

```
#!/bin/bash
# demonstrates set -e
# set -e means exit immediately if a command exited with a non zero status

set -e 
ls trumpet #no such file so $? is non-zero, hence the script aborts here
# you still get ls: cannot access trumpet: No such file or directory
echo "some other stuff" # will never be executed.
```

You may also combine the `e` with the `x` option like `set -ex` where :

> -x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.

This may help you debugging bash scripts.

**Reference**:[Set Manpage](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/seth.html)